# MySQL триггер для создания новой таблицы при вставке строки

Tags: mysql, sql

Не выходит написать триггер, создающий новую таблицу с именем, содержащим идентификатор строки исходной таблицы.

Проще говоря, имеется таблица `owners` с первичным ключом `owner_id`. При вставке в эту таблицу новой строки должна создаваться новая таблица, в имени которой будет присутствовать этот самый `owner_id`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `owners_after_insert`
    AFTER INSERT ON `owners`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
            CONCAT('`owner_', NEW.owner_id, '_members`') (
                `user_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
                , PRIMARY KEY(`user_id`)
            )
    END
```

В моём варианте мускул ругается на `CONCAT`. Как это обойти и реализовать обозначенное в вопросе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ на en.so с общим выводом о невозможности подобной операции:

> As far as I am aware, creating a table inside a trigger is not
>   possible. See here:
>
> http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,121849,122609#msg-122609
>
> Also have a look at the [Restrictions for Stored Functions section on
>   the Restrictions on Stored Routines, Triggers, and Events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[TR_CreateTableByOwnerID] on [dbo].[owners]
after insert as
begin

--Инициализация
declare @owner_ID int
declare @querySQL nvarchar(255)

--Получение ownerID из вставленной строки
select @owner_ID =ownerID from inserted



--Конструирование запроса на создание таблицы
set @querySQL='CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_'+cast(@owner_ID as varchar)+'
    ( id int identity, 
    Field1 varchar,
    Fiel2 int...)'
--Выполнения запроса из строки
exec sp_executesql @querySQL

end
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вами предложен странный синтаксис. Возможно я не вполне что-либо понял. У мускула (у меня версия 5.7) `trigger_time` (`AFTER`) и `trigger_event` (`INSERT`) идут перед `ON`, и обязательно наличие `FOR EACH ROW`. Не срабатывает к сожалению.

Comment: К сожалению понял, что в синтаксисе MySQL не силен(( Но я погуглил и понял, что можно применить ту же логику, что описана у меня. Вместо переменной querySQL надо объявить "PREPARE querySQL FROM ''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...". Получить ID, я так понял, можно командой NEW.ownerID. Собрав строку, ее можно выполнить как запрос командой EXECUTE querySQL. Вместо Вашей строки  "CONCAT('`owner_', NEW.owner_id, '_members`')" используйте "owner_?", а в момент выполнения передайте параметр командой USING (будет что-то типа EXECUTE querySQL USING @ownerID).

Comment: Вероятно это всё вполне работоспособно (в том числе и с т.н. подготавливаемыми запросами `Prepared Statements`), но не в мускуле, я пробовал. Подготавливаемые запросы в MySQL позволяют создавать таблицы, но не в теле триггера. Такое вот ограничение самой СУБД (ссылка на официальную документацию с описанием ограничений у меня в ответе дана). Фактически, решения нет. Может разве что каким-нибудь хаком на свой страх и риск, но тогда овчинка не будет стоить выделки, поскольку то, что не удалось обработать через триггер можно в общем-то без проблем решить средствами языка программирования. Селяви.

Comment: Еще проблему можно решить, вызвав из триггера хранимую процедуру, создающую таблицы (если это не попадает под ограничения).

Comment: Я не уверен, но скорее всего тоже подпадает.